# Is the supremum of a function squared the square of its supremum

Tags: analysis

Let $f$  be a holomorphic function on the open unit disc.

Is $(\sup \vert f \vert)^2 = \sup (\vert f\vert^2)$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with $f$ being a holomorphic function on the open unit disk. The square of the supremum of any set of non-negative numbers is the supremum of the squares.

Answer (score 5):

For weakly positive real numbers, the inequalities $x \le y$ and $x^2 \le y^2$ are equivalent. Since the modulus of the function is always weakly positive, this is all you need.

Comment: non-negative, to be precise...

Comment: @joriki: Sorry, I am living in a weakly positive country, will correct.

Comment: @joriki: I refuse to use "non-negative" and "non-positive" (or non-decreasing, etc), it goes against human cognitive functioning to gratuitously add negations.

Comment: Interesting. For my cognitive functioning, "non-negative" is a lot easier to parse than "weakly positive".

Comment: @joriki You should try it with a directed concept where you did not already "grow up" with the term.